# How to get the timestamp of performance profiling events in Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome Dev Tools how can I get the timestamp of performance profiling events so that I can match them with network events in the network tab?

Answer (score 1):

You can to use the performance tab in the dev tools.
Use the snapshot to profile the application.
Start using the application.
You can then analyse and save it. 
Tbh I don't know a way to get exact timestamps but you can make approximations by sliding the cursors as you examine timings between sequence of events, approximate timings for paint on load etc.

EDIT
Once you have profiled the application - you can get specific timings on network events by selecting the network dropdown. It should show each event with the time for execution when you hover over the event.